# Error uploading GeoJSON to Azure Maps Data Service

Tags: geojson, azure-maps

I have tried several attempts to upload a GeoJSON FeatureSet to the Azure Map Service REST API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/data/uploadpreview

The JSON I tried came from http://geojson.xyz/ - namely the "populated places simple" file, which you can download here:

https://d2ad6b4ur7yvpq.cloudfront.net/naturalearth-3.3.0/ne_50m_populated_places_simple.geojson

1,249 points, 175KB.

On POSTing to `/mapData/upload` I get a HTTP 200, and 'success' response message.

The response headers includes a location, which when I query I get a 200 back, with this error message in the body.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "400 BadRequest",
    "message":
      "Upload request failed.\nYour data has been removed " +
      "as we encountered the following problems with it:\n" +
      "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String[]]"
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richard, I wasn't able to repro your issue.

The file is indeed a valid GeoJSON file and I was able to successfully upload the file `ne_50m_populated_places_simple.geojson`(Downloaded from http://geojson.xyz/) using the [Map Data Service Upload API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/data/uploadpreview)

Please give it another try and feel free to let us know if you still see any issues.

Comment: Thank you, my bad here I think, for having a malformed body in the request.

Answer (score 0):

The team is investigating, but they say this is often due to issues with the GeoJSON file. Try pasting your GeoJSON into this site: http://geojson.io/ If you see any red in the side panel, hover over it and it should provide some insights into the issue.